# order by group then group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a phpbb mysql table, which creates a row with post_id topic_id and forum_id columns.

For every post, the data for a row is:

```
post_id topic_id forum_id
2       1        12
1       1        12
3       2        12
4       2        12
6       3        12
5       3        12
2       1        13
1       1        13
3       2        13
4       2        13
6       3        13
5       3        13
```

I want to get only the row with the min post_id of every topic_id to get something like:

```
post_id topic_id forum_id
1       1        12
3       2        12
5       3        12
1       1        13
3       2        13
5       3        13
```

could anyone help me? (i think about using order by then group by... but does not work as i thought...

Comment: See the manual for a better solution than those so far provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this...

```
select post_id, topic_id, forum_id 
from thetable t
where 
    (post_id,topic_id) = (select min(t1.post_id), t1.topic_id
               from thetable t1 
               where t1.topicid = t.topicid group by t1.topic_id)
```

This says grab all the records from thetable where the post_id and topic_id in the subselect pattern.

Comment: I chose to write it this way because i am not sure if the forum_id was always the same for the given topic_id and you were not concerned about the distinction of topic_id and forum_id combos

Comment: could you write it to select only where forum_id = 12 ??

Comment: add another predicate to the where clause ...   " and forum_id = 12" .. That should work..

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef58c/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE topic
    (`post_id` int, `topic_id` int, `forum_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO topic
    (`post_id`, `topic_id`, `forum_id`)
VALUES
    (2, 1, 12),
    (1, 1, 12),
    (3, 2, 12),
    (4, 2, 12),
    (6, 3, 12),
    (5, 3, 12),
    (2, 1, 13),
    (1, 1, 13),
    (3, 2, 13),
    (4, 2, 13),
    (6, 3, 13),
    (5, 3, 13)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select forum_id, topic_id, min(post_id) as min_post_id
from topic
group by forum_id, topic_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aef58c/2/0)**:

```
| forum_id | topic_id | min_post_id |
|----------|----------|-------------|
|       12 |        1 |           1 |
|       12 |        2 |           3 |
|       12 |        3 |           5 |
|       13 |        1 |           1 |
|       13 |        2 |           3 |
|       13 |        3 |           5 |
```

Comment: thats not working, i need an order by to get all data orderer by post_id then group all data by topic_id to get the row with min(post_id) on every topic_id